# javascript eval() doesn't work in php file

Tags: javascript, php, eval

The function in script section works very well but when i change it to `file.php` and open it on a server, the `eval` function doesn't work.

```
<?php 
echo "
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick=\"myFunction()\">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    eval(\"alert('it worked')\") ;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
";//end of echo
?>
```

Comment: You're code works for me. Check the HTML source (view source).

Comment: Can you show the version of code after removing php tags?

Comment: Is your php script executed at all? When you have called file.php and you check the source code in the browser, is the php tag still visible? The code works for me too...

Comment: @barry yeah it is executed but nothing alerted

Comment: @Tomasz @Jasny-ArnoldDaniels this is it `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    eval("alert('it worked')") ;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

</body>
</html>
`

Comment: This source works for me as html. If source of webpage when this is php file looks the same I don't see a reason why it would not work

Comment: Sure you have PHP running at all? It's not something builtin, you need to install stuff on the server first.

Comment: Try it with different browser.If it does'n work then the problem is    with your server.to be sure write another php code and try it.

Comment: You may have disabled the eval() function in php.ini. Check for "disable_functions" in php.ini file.

Comment: just forgive me guys i was vary stupid testing by alert wile i prevented page from adding alerts 

it worked well

Answer (score 0):

## Pay more attention.

```
eval(\"alert('it worked')\")
```

Must be coded:

```
  eval("("+alert('it worked')+")").
```

The bracket **"("** can make the code as a object instead of statement.

Answer (score 0):

Some server may disabled the eval function for security reason,

Try to check whether eval function is enabled or not by making the following code

```
<?php
if(function_exists('eval')) {
echo "eval function is enabled";
}
else {
echo "eval function is not enabled";
}
?>
```

If you got the else part in the code, this would be reason for not executing your code.

Note: Your code works perfectly works for me. so I dont think there is issue in your code.

Comment: it seems you didn't understand it we are talking about javascript eval function